# How to check the request handler in Moodle

Tags: php, web-services, soap, moodle

I have some methods in a Moodle 2.3 plugin that may be called through browser or webservice (Soap).

How can I check which is the current request handler to return ou print messages and etc?

I'm considering using the `$_SERVER` global, but an elegant way would be better.

Answer (score 0):

Each 'browser' page needs `$PAGE->url` setting to do output correctly, see [Page API](http://docs.moodle.org/dev/Page_API), so you potentially use `$PAGE->url` to determine what page you are on.

I'm not sure i'm understanding your question correctly though.

Comment: Not really. I managed to do the task by creating a new class and use `php_sapi_name()` in conjunction with `$_SERVER`.
My doubt was essencialy if Moodle has some API to deal with requests, like [CakePHP RequestHandler](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/request-handling.html).